# What is an encoding error for sprintf that should return -1?

Tags: c, gcc, error-handling, language-lawyer

I understand **snprintf** will return a negative value when **"an encoding error occurs"**

But what is a simple example of such an **"encoding error"** that will produce that result?

I'm working with **gcc 10.2.0** C compiler, and I've tried malformed format specifiers, unreasonably large numbers for field length, and even null format strings.

- Malformed format specifiers just get printed literally
- Unreasonably large numbers as length specifiers produce fatal errors
- Null format strings also produce fatal errors

This relates to repeatedly doing something like:

```
length += snprintf(...
```

to build up a formatted string.

That might be safe if it is certain *not* to return a negative value.

Advancing the buffer pointer by a negative length could cause it to go out of bounds. But I'm looking for a case where that would actually happen. If there is such a case then the added complexity of this may be warranted:

```
length += result = snprintf(...
```

So far I couldn't find a scenario where it would be worth adding complexity for a check of a value that the compiler may never produce. Maybe you can give a simple example of one.

Comment: For example, an invalid UTF-8 byte sequence in a string argument (assuming UTF-8 execution charset).

Comment: One example from the posix spec of when it can return a negative value: *The value of n is greater than {INT_MAX} or the number of bytes needed to hold the output excluding the terminating null is greater than {INT_MAX}.*

Comment: Also, compiler doesn't really matter; it's the system libc where snprintf is implemented that does.

Comment: @Sha wn when I tried using long n=((long)INT_MAX)*2L it produced a fatal error instead of returning -1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is an encoding error for sprintf that should return -1?

On my machine, `"%ls"` did not like the `0xFFFF` - certainly an encoding error.

```
  char buf[42];
  wchar_t s[] = { 0xFFFF,49,50,51,0 };
  int i = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "<%ls>", s);
  printf("%d\n", i);
```

Output

```
-1
```

---

Below code returned -1, but not so much due to encoding error as for pathological format.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  size_t n = 0xFFFFFFFFLLu + 1;
  char *fmt = malloc(n);
  if (fmt == NULL) {
    puts("OOM");
    return -42;
  }
  memset(fmt, 'x', n);
  fmt[n - 1] = '\0';
  char buf[42];
  int i = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, fmt);
  printf("%d %x\n", i, (unsigned) i);
  free(fmt);
  return 7;
}
```

Output

```
-1 ffffffff
```

---

I did get a surprising -1 when passing a too big a size, even though the `snprintf()` only needed 6 bytes.

```
  char buf[42];
  int i = snprintf(buf, 4299195472, "Hello");
  printf("%d\n", i);
```

Output

```
-1
```

---

I was able to come up with a short example returning -1 on a `*fprintf()` to `stdout` due to *orientation* conflict.

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int w = wprintf(L"Hello wide world\n");
  wprintf(L"%d\n", w);
  int s = printf("Hello world\n");
  wprintf(L"%d\n", s);
}
```

Output

```
Hello wide world
17
-1
```

Comment: I get no output, gcc MSYS2 C on Windows 10 either in Eclipse or cmd shell, same result. With gdb installed running under Eclipse, it dies in the snprintf and never returns.

Comment: @TedShaneyfelt There are a few code snippets here.  Did  all 4 snippets die?

Comment: The results for snprintf snippets: 2, crash, 5.  I'm not looking for wprintf or printf. They can't be put directly together, but wrapped in blocks, without flush there's no output and it crashes in the second block as expected. wprintf and printf are diferent functions that I'm not interested in or asking about so I didn't bother with the final example program.

Comment: @TedShaneyfelt What did the first `char buf[42]; wchar_t s[] = { 0xFFFF,49,50,51,0 };
  int i = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "<%ls>", s); printf("%d\n", i);` do for you?

Comment: Outputs digit 2

Answer (score 3):

Normally you only expect an error from printf and family when an output error occurs.  From the Linux man page:

> If an output error is encountered, a negative value is returned.

So if you are outputting to a FILE and an output error of some kind (EPIPE, EIO) occurs, you'll get a negative return value.  For s[n]printf, since there's no output, there would never be a negative return value.

The standard talks about the possibility of an "encoding error", but only defines what that means with respect to wide character streams, with a note that byte streams might need to convert to wide streams in some cases.

> An encoding error occurs if the character sequence presented to the underlying
> mbrtowc function does not form a valid (generalized) multibyte character, or if the code
> value passed to the underlying wcrtomb does not correspond to a valid (generalized) multibyte character. The wide character input/output functions and the byte input/output
> functions store the value of the macro EILSEQ in errno if and only if an encoding error
> occurs.

That would seem to imply that you can get an encoding error if you use the `%ls` or `%lc` formats to convert a wide string or characters to bytes.  Not sure if there are any other cases where it could occur.

Comment: Yes, if it didn't specifically mention the possibility of an encoding error I wouldn't bother looking. Funny the errors I found that didn't return positive or zero didn't return at all. Maybe if they ever catch those fatal errors and return instead it'll be -1. If that's all it is there seems no reason to check the result for negativity when providing a constant format string without a bogus %* value.